# Angular callback within "onchange" directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Very specific question but for reuse: I am trying to pass an angular callback into a javascript directive.... see below. (attempting `product.id` through the onchange event)

```js
$scope.fileNameChanged = function(folder, id){
        console.log(folder + " " + id);
  }
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
  <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
      <span class="uploadButton">Choose...</span>
      <input type="file" id="productsFile" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChanged('products', product.id)" name="file">
    </span>
  </form>
</div>
```

The console just shows `Uncaught ReferenceError: product is not defined` but I absolutely know that product.id is defined, I've done `{{product.id}}` within the ng-repeat just to display the text and it appears just fine....

I'm unsure as to whether I should be using `{{..}}` within the onchange argument so I tried just `{{product.id}}` and got `Error: [$compile:nodomevents]`.

I am using onchange because ng-change doesn't support file input, or from what I have read.

Any suggestions would be absolutely fantastic, I am not specifically looking to get product.id through that callback but any angular scope variable....

Comment: Where is this form set up? Is it in your controller scope or something like a modal window?

Comment: The form is in a HTML document using ng-view and routing to change controller for each view.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to answer my own question but this is my very valid work-around!

I used the element's Id directive....

```
<span class="uploadButton">Choose...</span> <input type="file" id="{{product.id}}" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChanged('products', this.id)" name="file">
```

And got it using the `this.id`, now as a real solution to passing angular scope through `onchange=""` I really don't think it is wise, but in this instance it is something that I wouldn't mind being the element's Id anyway.

I hope this becomes of use to other people.